# Check if a python function is builtin

Tags: python, python-2.7, built-in

How can I check whether a python function is a built-in function?

I want something like this:

```
def abc(x):
  return x

is_builtin(abc)
```

should return False

```
import os
is_builtin(os.path.join)
```

should return True

```
from os import *
is_builtin(path.join)
```

should return True

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: check [Python Doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) , I think builtin and standard library is different.

Comment: @TimCastelijns That won't work for `os.path.join`.

Comment: May I ask what the use case is?

Comment: What dose `built-in` mean? `os.path.join` is not a `built-in` function in Python.

Comment: Batteries Included... but all of them are not `built-in`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import sys
import os

lib_path = os.path.dirname(os.__file__)

def is_battery_inc(arg):
    if hasattr(arg, "__call__"):
        if hasattr(arg, "__module__"):
            module = sys.modules[arg.__module__]
            if module == __builtin__:
                return True
            if hasattr(module, "__file__"):
                return lib_path == os.path.dirname(module.__file__)
    return False

def test():
    pass

print(is_battery_inc(os.path.join))
print(is_battery_inc(test))
print(is_battery_inc(map))
```